# The side-by-side revision history is not

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The diff within [revision history for posts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/29900/revisions) are stacked on top of each other instead of side-by-side:

[image: revision history screen shot]

[Another example](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/12765/revisions)

Comment: Odd. If you pick "side-by-side markdown" it works, but not side-by-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed.

[image: screenshot of corrected issue.]